# Numpy array with images of different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I need to build a numpy array with images of different shapes to training a Fully convolutional network, the array need to have rank 4, the shape that I need is [64, None, None, 3], and the code that I´m using is like that:

```
batch_x = []
for i, j in enumerate(index_array):
  image = cv2.imread(self.filenames[j], is_color)
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  batch_x.append(image)

batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
np.reshape(batch_x, (64, None, None, 3))
```

But the numpy consider each image as a separated object.

Comment: Is batch_x correct before the reshape?

Comment: @Mike67, yes, I print the batch_x in my code, and it´s correct.